# Swift: Array of audio files

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, audio

Using Swift 2 how would I create an array of audio files to be used on a collection view?

There are 4 options "Ocean", "Birds", "Nature", "Waves" and they are displayed as cells.

When a cell is clicked, I need it to play the sound. Can you please help?

```
    var imageArray = [UIImage(named: "ocean"),UIImage(named: "birds"),UIImage(named: "nature"),UIImage(named: "wave")]
var nameArray = ["Ocean","Birds","Nature","Waves"]



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.imageArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! homeCollectionViewCell

    cell.iconImage?.image = imageArray[indexPath.item!]
    cell.label.text = nameArray[indexPath.item!]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Where do you wan to play the audio? Same `viewController` or navigating to a different?

Comment: viewcontroller @Santosh

Comment: Did you implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method? If not then you should use that to perform any action on selecting particular `cell` in a `tableView`. So create one more array of your audio files and get the audio file using `indexPath.row` in your audio files array.

Comment: yes @Santosh but i do not know how to make an array of audio files do you?????

Comment: Where are your audio files stored? Locally or server?

Comment: Then read the files using `let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType: ".mp3")`. You can refer this to list directories and get the file from directory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430685/how-get-list-of-folders-and-files-from-resource-folder-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to play the sound? Have you done it yet? 
If so, you need to use the following function and do something like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        //grab the sound from the array
        let sound = your_array_with_sounds[indexPath.row]

        //if you want to play the sound in this view:
           <code to play the sound>          
        //if you want to play the sound in another view:
           <perform the segue and pass the sound to the view you want>
    }
```

I hope this help. If not, add a bit more of information to your question and we will help you.

Comment: Hi sorry if i wasn't clear i know how to play sound all i need is an array of sounds do you know how?????? thanks @Amandeu_Andrade

Comment: Do you want to make a request from somewhere to download the sounds or do you have the sounds and will import them into the project?

Comment: i have them an will import them please i just need an array of audio files or sounds @Amadeu_Andrade

Comment: Something like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762368/pushing-sound-files-to-an-array-with-swift
?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the AVAudioPlayer Class for Play the Audio
For that you need to import the below class

import AVFoundation

you need to create the function with Following code

```
let audioName:String!


func playAudio(){
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(
                NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(audioName, 
                ofType: "mp3")!)

        var error: NSError?

        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: &error)

        if let err = error {
            println("audioPlayer error \(err.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            audioPlayer?.delegate = self
            audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()
        }
      if let player = audioPlayer {
               player.play()
       }
}
```

in collection View

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
          audioName = arrayName[indexPath.row]
}
```

Swift 4.0

```
let audioName:String!
func playAudio(){
    let url = NSURL.fileURL(
        withPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: audioName,
                                              ofType: "mp3")!)
    var error: NSError?

    let audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
    audioPlayer?.delegate = self
    audioPlayer?.prepareToPlay()

    if let player = audioPlayer {
        player.play()
    }
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
          audioName = arrayName[indexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: The current version of Swift is 2.2, with 3 coming soon. You should really avoid posting answers that are in Swift 1, it's not very useful. :)